# I need remove word message by office.js

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, office365, office-js

how I can remove word message when press close button on the word document
the message is:
"Want to save your change to xxx.docx
if you click don't save a recent copy of this file will be temporarily available "

I did not need the user save change in the document because I have custom save button it is saved in my database the word message is confused the use.

Answer (score 1):

this is not possible to do with the API. Alternatively you could save the document to avoid showing that message.